# Execute before confirm

Tags: javascript, setinterval, confirm

Is there any way to stop interval when function is on before confirm fires up?

```
function check(){
    clearInterval(interval_id);
    if(confirm('Stream time is running out. Do you want to continue?'))
        //
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hook your own code into confirm, if that's somewhat what you want:

```
window.proxiedConfirm = window.confirm;
window.confirm = function() {
   // custom interval code here
   return window.proxiedConfirm.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

You could of course listen to responses manually as well:

```
window.proxiedConfirm = window.confirm;
window.confirm = function() {

   // custom interval code here

   var result = window.proxiedConfirm.apply(this, arguments);

   if(result) {
      // start interval again?
   }

   return result;
};
```

Comment: @AndreshPodzimovsky: I'm not sure I follow your question, then. what is it you want to do, that you're not already doing in the code you've posted?

Comment: The problem is that now with your code interval does not stop generally.

Comment: @AndreshPodzimovsky: then there's probably something wrong with the part of your code that stops it. you need to be more specific and show more of what you're doing and what you want, for us to be able to help you.

Comment: It is all code. At specific moment this function is called. When it is called i need firstly stop interval and only the show confirm.

Comment: @AndreshPodzimovsky: it's not "all code". You're not defining `interval_id` anywhere. No interval is being set in the code you've posted, and `check` is never called. `clearInterval` exists and works; if you're having a problem with it, then something *else* is wrong. You can't just show us your call to `clearInterval`

Comment: interval_id = setInterval('$(\'#camera\').remove()', 20000);
setTimeout(check, 40000);

Comment: @AndreshPodzimovsky: [The code you've posted works](http://jsfiddle.net/5ww4Z/). Something else is wrong. You need to provide more context. The problem is not within any part of the code that you've posted.

Comment: @AndreshPodzimovsky: yes, that is the fiddle I posted. it contains two intervals. As in your code, the `remove` interval is being cleared after the confirm. You can see it happening twice before the confirm shows up, and then never again. This is exactly what `clearInterval` does, and it seems to be what you're asking for. Is there anything you're having a problem with?

Comment: @AndreshPodzimovsky: The interval stops in the video you've posted. `Remove` happens twice before the confirm, then **never again**, which means that the interval was stopped.